# Comparing user's facebook/twitter friends to site's users in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, twitter

I'm wondering if someone could help guide the approach to this fairly common problem:

I'm building a simple site which a user connects their twitter account to sign up. I'd like to create an interface which shows them which of their twitter friends are already using the site.

So I can get a list the user's twitter friends, and a list of the site's users (which all have the twitter screen name as username, but I'm wondering the most efficient method to compare these lists and create a variable with the commonalities.

As an aside, given the Twitter API returns IDs, should I save the twitter user's ID (in addition to their username) when they create an account?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create [Sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) out of them, and use the [intersection](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) method:

```
intersection_set = set(list_a).intersection(list_b)
```

Comment: Thanks! Wondering, how would you recommend getting the sets. Right now I can get the IDs of the user's twitter friends. And I have the screennames saved on the site. But should I be saving the twitter IDs when they link to my site and then just use that number?  Or is there a more scalable approach?

Answer (score 1):

You should store the twitter user's ID because the username can change at any time, but the id will always be the same.  You should be comparing the id's, not the usernames in the intersection_set that Ofri recommends.

Comment: Okay, then one more question. I can get a list of twitter friend IDs. I now have the twitter ID stored in the profile of the user. What's the quickest way to pull those IDs into a list?  Obviously users = User.objects.all() or profiles = Profile.objects.all() doesn't pull in a comparable list.  Thx

Comment: I can only do AppEngine queries in my head, but there's probably something comparable in Django models: twitter_friend_ids = [user.twitter_id for user in Users.all().filter('twitter_id IN', id_list)]