# Method for comparing twitter users to site users in Django / Python

Tags: python, django, twitter

This is a follow up to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137126/comparing-users-facebook-twitter-friends-to-sites-users-in-python-django). I'm using the below code to get a user's friends and then compare them to the users of my site to show a "Friends already using this site" list.

It's working perfectly, but is this an efficient way to do it?  Any recommendations?

*in views.py*

```
# Get Twitter Friends
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='TWITTER_TOKEN',
                      consumer_secret='TWITTER_SECRET',
                      access_token_key='request.user.get_profile.oauth_token',
                      access_token_secret='request.user.get_profile.oauth_secret')
friends = api.GetFriendIDs(request.user.username)

# Compare friends with High Five users    
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(twitter_id__in = friends['ids'])
```

*in template.html*

```
<h2>Friends</h2>
    <ul>
    {% for profile in profiles %}
        <li>
            <a href="/user/{{ profile.user.username }}">
                <img src="{{ profile.profile_image_url }}" />
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Why should this be inefficient? What other options should you have other than performing the two different queries?  Must we know what your particular usecase is without providing some more coherent information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the right thing.  What's your concern?  Is the page loading slowly?  If so, consider loading a page without this information, then using an ajax call to fetch the list of friends who are using the site.  That way, at least you can have your user looking at a page with a loading graphic that says "fetching your list of friends....." instead of simply waiting a long time for the page to load.

Comment: Thanks .. It's not that I was concerned. I'm just new at this and like to check in and make sure I'm doing it efficiently. I like the AJAX idea and need to brush up on those methods. :)